# I installed pyaudio by conda install but my laptop is not taking audio from microphone

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pyaudio

def takeCommand():

```
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Listening...")
    r.pause_threshold = 0.8
    audio = r.listen(source)

try:
    print("Recognizing...")    
    query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
    print("User said: {} \n".format(query))

except Exception as e:
    # print(e)    
    print("Say that again please...")  
    return "None"
return query
```

above code is not taking voice from microphone

Answer (score 0):

just install pyaudio using the conda install and it will work the same .